# cocos2d, tile map game

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Do any of you guys now some tricks or tips on how to make a tile map game that has certain tiles moving across the board. I always wanted to learn this trick , but I do not not know how to do this. I have tile map editor and everything set up. I am trying to make a platform game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would very much check out this tutorial for an excellent guide to making a tile based game, specifically, in cocos2d: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d